# In a c# program, is there a way to open a file.txt, without using the entire file path

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a c# program, which deals with opening, reading and writing to a .txt file. This program will need to be submitted, however, when it is submitted the path that the program uses to find the file will change and the program will no longer work.

Currently, the file path looks like this:

`"C:\\file path\\file name.txt"`

So is there a way around using the entire file path? can I just have the program look in the same local folder it is in?

Comment: What is your program ? Console Application ? Are you using .Net Framework ?
You can pass argument when you start your app or edit a config file appsettings.json for example or something else like this, if its Graphical or any other type of app with user interface input , you can get the path from the user

Comment: You can certainly use relative pathing, but it requires you to know where that file is *relative* to your path.

Comment: @AnGG .net Framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using Windows Forms: `string path = Application.StartupPath + "/filename.txt"`

If console app: `string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Edit: As pointed out by Çöđěxěŕ, you should use `Path.Combine`to join the startup path and file name together:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Use `Path.Combine`, don't concatenate paths like that.

Comment: `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` also workfs for WPF, but note there is a difference between `GetExecutingAssembly()` and `GetEntryAssembly`

Comment: Is there a way to customise this location so the text file doesn't have to be in the bin>debug folder? if not it's fine just wondering

Comment: @Kiejo You can alter this path in any way you like. If you expect the file to exist in the executable's parent directory, for example, you could find that location using `System.IO.Directory.GetParent`, for example. You could combine the parent directory with the name of another child directory as well. However you want it to be, there's a way to do it, you just need to figure out the desired rules and how to implement them in your program.

Comment: Thanks again! @Audiopolis